# Conditional response types based upon function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that calls a method in a library, which returns different data depending on the parameters provided to the method.

A simplified example:

```js
import aMethod from "aLib";

const aParam = "foo"; // or in other cases: "bar";
const response = aMethod(aParam);
```

If `aParam` is `"foo"`, the response back from `aMethod` has a different shape than if I pass `aParam` as `"bar"`. For example, the `response` from `someParam === "foo"` will have a shape like so:

```js
type TFooResponse = {
  someObject: object;
  someString: string;
}
```

And if I pass `"bar"`, then the shape of `response` will be:

```js
type TBarResponse = {
  someArray: array;
}
```

How best should I handle stating *~ if `aParam === "foo"` use `TFooResponse`, else use `TBarResponse`?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you re looking for somehting like this:

```
type TType<T extends "foo" | "bar"> = {
    a: T,
    c: T extends "foo" ? TFooType : TBarType
}
```

Or for your exmaple:

```
function <T extends "foo" | "bar"> aMethod(aParam: T): T extends "foo" ? TFooType : TBarType {
    /**
     * 
     */
}
```

Comment: This works well, thanks Michel. Another option a friend mentioned is using overloads, so if anyone else is coming to this post that might be a good fit too, depends on your specific problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads